# "Error: n() should only be called in a data context" when using group_by and summarize

Tags: r, count, grouping, summarize

I have a homework question: "For each age range find the percent of patients who were readmitted after 30 days and display the results in a bar chart."

I ran the following code and got "Error: n() should only be called in a data context"

```
cont_table_4<-diabetic_data%>%
  select(age, readmitted)%>%
  filter(readmitted==">30")%>%
  group_by(age)%>%
  summarize(count=n())%>%
  arrange(desc(count()))
```

I used this almost the exact same format for a question: "Find out which sub-specialty has the most readmissions. Then print the breakdown for that sub-specialty by race." And it worked perfectly. I emailed my instructor a screenshot of the code and error and she said the issue is with count() function call even though the error refers to n(). I don't really know what to do with that information. I have loaded dplyr and plyr, unloaded each of them and tried again with just one of them and I get the same error message. I have looked up many Q&A regarding this error but can't find what I'm looking for. I'm a student just beginning to learn R and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please us `dput` to show a subset of your data,  The last line seems to be the issue `arrange(desc(count))` instead of `count()`

Answer (score 2):

Issue would be the `count()` as a function instead of the 'count' column created before the last line

```
library(dplyr)
diabetic_data%>%
  select(age, readmitted)%>%
  filter(readmitted==">30")%>%
  group_by(age)%>%
  summarize(count=n())%>%
  arrange(desc(count))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What needs to be changed?

Comment: @LeighAnneRobinson  I am answering only based on the code you showed.  In your code, the last line is `count()` which is a function and not the column in `summarise` step.  It is changed to `count`

Comment: @LeighAnneRobinson If the errorr is happening before the `arrange` step, may be you don't have any rows after the `filter` step.  What is the output from `diabetic_data%>%
  select(age, readmitted)%>%
  filter(readmitted==">30")` Are you getting any rows?

Comment: I get a table with 106,635 observations of 2 variables. It is just each time a given age range is associated with >30. I just did cont_table_4$age[1] and it returned the age range 10-20 and all of the levels for age. I'm not sure I trust  this is the correct answer.

Comment: @LeighAnneRobinson As I mentioned in the comments, please show a small reprodcucible examplee and expected output.  It would make things faster